# Textmate can't run boot.rb on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, textmate

I can run my Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.2 application, normaly, all goes fine, rake commands and web server.

But some Textmate bundles that need run

`require "#{project}/config/boot"`

when executes

`require 'bundler/setup'`

crash:

```
.../config/boot.rb:3:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

An example of these bundles is "**Show DB Schema for Current Class**”

I use rvm, and is installed successfully and runs normally (I think so)

I have been looking for information about this issue without success...so I begin to think that people don't use these bundles,isn't it?

Comment: I don't know if it is just som env you need to set in Textmate settings. Have you looked into that?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't catch it, I have checked all I can see about Env variables, and paths, and all seems to be correct. I really think people don't use it

Comment: I tried replicating your problem. I just got other similar looking problems.